# Does the prince of Liechtenstein have veto power over legislation directly passed by his subjects?

Tags: constitutional-law, legislative-power

I understand that the Constitution Peace Initiative was rejected so the prince may exercise his veto over a referendum about the abolishment of the monarchy and thereby the recalling of the prince, so clearly, princely veto may be invoked at least in *some* legislative actions taken directly via referenda, but does it extend to every other legislation or does the people truly have the final say, and thereby the monarch is compelled to act within how he understands the best interest of his subjects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Article 9 of the [Liechtenstein Constitution](https://www.gesetze.li/konso/pdf/1921.015):

> Art. 9
> Jedes Gesetz bedarf zu seiner Gültigkeit der Sanktion des Landesfürsten.
>
> *Every law requires the sanction of the Prince Regnant in order to be valid.*

There is no exception for general laws, whether made by the Parliament or the People.

Note that unlike Switzerland, there is no distinction between popular initiatives (which federally is only possible for the constitution in Switzerland; Swiss people cannot propose a bill directly to the Parliament for consideration) and referendums; popular initiatives in Liechtenstein do not automatically go to vote but instead first go to the Parliament for discussion; if they go to the people due to parliamentary decision or rejection, it is considered as a referendum.

This is also clear from Art. 66 paragraphs 5 and 6:

> 5. Dem Referendum unterliegende Gesetzesbeschlüsse werden erst nachDurchführung der Volksabstimmung beziehungsweise nach fruchtlosem Ablauf der für die Stellung des Begehrens nach Vornahme einer Volksabstimmung normierten dreissigtägigen Frist dem Landesfürsten zur Sanktion vorgelegt.
> 6. Hat der Landtag einen ihm im Wege der Volksinitiative (Art. 64 Bst.
>    c) zugegangenen ausgearbeiteten und erforderlichenfalls mit einem Bedeckungsvorschlag versehenen Gesetzentwurf abgelehnt, so ist derselbe der
>    Volksabstimmung zu unterziehen. Die Annahme des Entwurfes durch die
>    wahlberechtigten Landesbürger vertritt in diesem Falle den sonst zur
>    Annahme eines Gesetzes erforderlichen Beschluss des Landtages.
>
> *5) Legislative resolutions subject to the referendum are only
> submitted to the Prince Regnant for sanction after the referendum has
> been carried out or after the 30-day period standardized for
> submitting a request for a referendum has expired without success.*
>
> *6) If the Parliament rejects a bill that has been drafted and, if
> necessary, provided with a proposal of funding by way of a popular
> initiative (art. 64 letter c), then the bill must be submitted to a
> referendum. In this case, the acceptance of the draft by the citizens
> of the state who are entitled to vote represents the resolution of the
> state parliament that is otherwise required for the adoption of a law.*

---

> the prince may exercise his veto over a referendum about the abolishment of the monarchy and thereby the recalling of the prince,

This is actually the only thing the Prince ***cannot*** veto. Other constitutional reforms require the princely approval.

Article 112 paragraph 2:

> 2. Abänderungen oder allgemein verbindliche Erläuterungen dieses
>    Grundgesetzes können sowohl von der Regierung als auch vom Landtage
>    oder im Wege der Initiative (Art. 64) beantragt werden. Sie erfordern auf
>    Seite des Landtages Stimmeneinhelligkeit seiner anwesenden Mitglieder
>    oder eine auf zwei nacheinander folgenden Landtagssitzungen sich aussprechende Stimmenmehrheit von drei Vierteln derselben, allenfalls eine Volksabstimmung (Art. 66) und jedenfalls die nachfolgende Zustimmung des
>    Landesfürsten, **abgesehen von dem Verfahren zur Abschaffung der Monarchie (Art. 113).**
>
> *2. Amendments to, or generally binding explanations of, this Constitution can be requested by both the Government and the Parliament or through an initiative (Art. 64). They require unanimous votes by the members present or a majority of three quarters of the votes expressed at two consecutive Parliamentary sessions from the Parliament, if necessary a referendum (Art. 66), and in any case the subsequent approval of the Prince Regnant, **except from the procedure for the abolition of the monarchy (Art. 113).***

For abolition of the Monarchy, the process is complicated, but the Prince has no power over the final decision made by the people. Several steps are needed:

1. A proposal to abolish the monarchy, proposed by no less than 1500 eligible voters, is accepted by the people.
2. A republican constitution is drafted by the Parliament.
3. The Prince may propose a counter proposal that does not have to be republican (but technically it may be).
4. If the Prince proposed an alternative, the current constitution, the republican draft and the princely draft are all present as options in a referendum. Each voter can vote for two options in this referendum.
5. The two options receiving most votes (or the current constitution and the republican draft if the Prince did not propose an alternative) will be present in another referendum. Each voter can only vote for one option.
6. The option receiving an absolute majority is adopted (or retained).

Comment: So the exact opposite as I understood it. Would a president take the place of the prince to veto or approve legislation or what would retaining the same constitution mean? A more direct form of legislation without anyone to veto or having to approve legislation by referenda?

Comment: @kisspuska if the current constitution is retained then the current constitution is retained in its entirety, that is, including all the provisions regarding the constitutional monarchy.

Comment: Gotcha! Would the citizenry be permitted to start a popular initiate with 1500 in support to propose a constitution of its own?

Comment: (Very insightful answer with the Swiss comparison, btw)